# Java set method not working

Tags: java

Hello I'm new to programming and a first time poster here. I'm having trouble getting a Java application to display the correct values assigned via Set methods in a public class. Specifically the CreatePurchase application returns 0 for all 3 user defined variables (invoiceNumber, saleAmount, salesTax) which are Set in the Purchase public class.

Set and display the values here

```
public class Purchase
{
private int invoiceNumber;
private double saleAmount;
private double salesTax;
public int getInvoiceNumber()
{
    return invoiceNumber;
}
public void setInvoiceNumber(int inv)
{
    inv = invoiceNumber;
}
public double getSaleAmount()
{
    return saleAmount;
}
public void setSaleAmount(double sale)
{
    sale = saleAmount;
}
public double getSalesTax()
{
    return salesTax;
}   
public void setSalesTax(double tax)
{
    tax = saleAmount *.05;
    tax = salesTax;
}  
public static void displayPurchase(Purchase aPurch)
{
    System.out.println("Purchase invoice number is " + aPurch.getInvoiceNumber() + "and the sale amount is " + aPurch.getSaleAmount() + "the taxable amount is " +aPurch.getSalesTax());
}
}
```

This is the CreatePurchase class that prompts the user for the variables and calls the method to display the values for the new object

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CreatePurchase
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
  Purchase aPurchase;
  aPurchase = getPurchaseInfo();
  Purchase.displayPurchase(aPurchase);
}
public static Purchase getPurchaseInfo()
{
  Purchase tempPur = new Purchase();
  int invoice;
  double value;
  double value2;
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter the invoice number:");
  invoice = input.nextInt();
  while(invoice < 1000 || invoice > 8000)
  {
     System.out.println("You made an invalid selection");
     System.out.println("You entered " + invoice);
     System.out.println("Please enter a whole number between 1000 and 8000");
     invoice = input.nextInt();
  }
  tempPur.setInvoiceNumber(invoice);
  System.out.println("Enter the amount of the sale:");
  value = input.nextDouble();
  value2 = (value * .05);
  while(value < 0)
  {
     System.out.println("You made an invalid selection");
     System.out.println("You entered " + value);
     System.out.println("Please enter a non negative number");
     value = input.nextDouble();
     value2 = (value *.05);
  }
  tempPur.setSaleAmount(value);
  tempPur.setSalesTax(value2);
  return tempPur;
  }
}
```

Any direction or advice on how to get the values entered to set and display properly would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: I flipped the salesTax = tax line but the values still return 0 from the display method.

Comment: [use a debugger](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html)? maybe is a rounding issue...

Comment: That did it, thank you all so much for the help!! I do apologize for duplicating the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**All setters need to be modified as below**:

```
public void setSalesTax(double tax)
{
    tax = saleAmount *.05;
    //tax = salesTax; <-- This line is wrong..
    this.salesTax= tax ;  // Change this line and it should work...
}

public void setInvoiceNumber(int inv)
{
    //inv = invoiceNumber ; --> Invalid setting
    this.invoiceNumber = inv; // Correct setting
}

public void setSaleAmount(double sale)
{
    //sale = saleAmount;  --> Invalid setting
    this.saleAmount = sale; // Correct setting
}
```

**Reason:**

tax is local variable which is specific to the method setSalesTax.

salesTax is global variable for the object.

While setting value in your object, you need to set it/assign in the  global variable salesTax

To avoid confusions, The **best way to use a setter** would be:
Object Class:

```
private double amount;
public void setAmount (double amount)
{
   this.amount = amount;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The setter needs to assign the new value to the instance field.

```
public void setSaleAmount(double sale)
{
   sale = saleAmount;
}
```

Yours do the opposite now, switch the assignment around:

```
public void setSaleAmount(final double sale)
{
   this.saleAmount = sale;
}
```

You can also optionally add `final` to the parameter (since you don't intend to change it), and make it clear what the instance field is by using `this.`. Purely optional, but good practice, and in this case either addition would have resulted in a compile-time error to alert you of the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Your assignments are wrong(for the setters).

It should be `salesTax` that is set:

```
public void setSalesTax(double tax)
{
    tax = saleAmount *.05;
    tax = salesTax; /* wrong assignment(for the purpose) */
}
```

And so on for your other class variables.

Remember: `Setters` and `Getters` are used to modify a class' variables.

Answer (score 1):

**It is because you do not set the new Value to your object value.**

The correct way would be

```
public void setSalesTax(double tax)
{
    tax = saleAmount *.05;
    salexTax = tax; //THIS is the mistake
}
```

Everytime you want to assign a value to an Object, Integer, or whatever, it goes from left to right. So, if you write:

```
int value=5;
int value2=10;
value2=value;
```

Value2 is 5 then.

Answer (score 0):

Your setter method is wrong. You must use actual variable on LHS instead of formal argument.

for Ex, setInvoceNumber method should be like below :

```
public void setInvoiceNumber(int inv)
{
     invoiceNumber = inv ;
}
```

Here inv is formal argument while invoiceNumber is actual variable which is going to store your value in object. You were assigning value of `invoiceNumber` to `inv` variable which has no effect in your code. Same goes for all your setter method.